# color conversion from RGB to YIQ

Tags: matrices

I want to convert RGB color to YIQ. AS my knowledge the formula is below:

[image: Formula for conversion of RGB to YIQ]

To practice this math i went a to this link [Color Conversion](http://www.picturetopeople.org/color_converter.html).
I enter here RGB values 32,65,32. I found the result is YIQ = (0.201, -0.035, -0.068);[link of the Result.](http://www.picturetopeople.org/p2p/picture_to_people_colors.p2p/color_converter?color_space=RGB&color_channel1=32&color_channel2=65&color_channel3=32)

My problem is that i have calculated the YIQ value by using my calculator Casio fx-991es. But my result and the result of this web page is not same.
My result is 51.371,-9.042,-17.32.

In the calculator i have first set the constant values in a 3x3 matrix named as MatA and then the RGB value in a 3x1 matrix named as MatB. Then multiply them.

Can anyone tell why my result is not same as the website result?

i have got a solution that i have to divide the result by 255 to get these value as YIQ value .But i want to know that why i have to divide by 255.
 And when i want to convert YIQ to RGB, i have to multiply the result by 255 to get as RGB value.
My problem has solved but i want to know the reason.Please anyone clarify it.

Comment: Try dividing your values by 255.

Comment: If you read the wikipedia entry that you got that image from, immediately above it, it says $R,G,B,Y \in [0,1]$. Normalize as Reactant says

Comment: yes..it is right. now my answer has matched. but why i have to divide by 255?@ Reactant

Comment: @BlackSwan You need to divide by 255 to normalize the RGB colors. By normalizing, you bring the values into the range 0-1. For RGB, because each channel ranges from 0-255, in order to bring the values into the 0-1 range, you need to divide by 255